# R - how to make PCA biplot more readable

Tags: r, plot, pca

I have a set of observations with 23 variables.

When I use prcomp and biplot to plot the results I run into several problems:

1. the actual plot only occupies half of the frame (x < 0), but the plot is centered on 0, so half of space is wasted
2. two variables clearily dominate the results, so all other arrows are clumped together and I can't read a thing

ad 1. I tried setting xlim and/or ylim, but I'm obviously doing something wrong since the plot is all messed up when I do

ad 2. Can I just somehow make the arrow labels placed more apart so that I can read them? Or maybe I could just plot the arrows without the two longest ones (kind of zoom-in)?

[image: My PCA plot]

Addendum: is it possible to have biplot draw the labels in a different color than the arrows?

Also: is it problematic if the x and y axes are not proportional (they graph shows intervals of different length on x and y). 
I think this would skew the angels between arrows, and that kind of resizing is not a similarity transformation.
Is it possible to force biplot to keep a 1:1 aspect ratio, or to draw the plot as a rectangle and not a square?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you can use `xlim` and `ylim`. Also, have a look at the `expand` argument for `?biplot`. Unfortunately, you did not provide any data, so let's take some sample data:

```
a <- princomp(USArrests)
```

Below the result of just calling `biplot`:

```
biplot(a)
```

[image]

And now one can "zoom in" to have a closer look at "Murder" and "Rape" using `xlim` and `ylim` and also use the scaling argument `expand` from `?biplot`:

```
biplot(a, expand=10, xlim=c(-0.30, 0.0), ylim=c(-0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]

Please note the different scaling on the top and right axis due to the `expand` factor.

Does this help to make your plot mare readable?

**EDIT**

You also asked whether it is possible to have different colors for labels and arrows. `biplot` does not support this, what you could do is to copy the code of `stats:::biplot.default` and then change it according to your needs (change `col` argument when `plot`, `axis` and `text` is used).

Alternatively, you could use `ggplot` for the biplot. In the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578355/plotting-pca-biplot-with-ggplot2/6579572#6579572), a simple biplot function is implemented. You could change the code as follows:

```
PCbiplot <- function(PC, x="PC1", y="PC2", colors=c('black', 'black', 'red', 'red')) {
    # PC being a prcomp object
    data <- data.frame(obsnames=row.names(PC$x), PC$x)
    plot <- ggplot(data, aes_string(x=x, y=y)) + geom_text(alpha=.4, size=3, aes(label=obsnames), color=colors[1])
    plot <- plot + geom_hline(aes(0), size=.2) + geom_vline(aes(0), size=.2, color=colors[2])
    datapc <- data.frame(varnames=rownames(PC$rotation), PC$rotation)
    mult <- min(
        (max(data[,y]) - min(data[,y])/(max(datapc[,y])-min(datapc[,y]))),
        (max(data[,x]) - min(data[,x])/(max(datapc[,x])-min(datapc[,x])))
        )
    datapc <- transform(datapc,
            v1 = .7 * mult * (get(x)),
            v2 = .7 * mult * (get(y))
            )
    plot <- plot + coord_equal() + geom_text(data=datapc, aes(x=v1, y=v2, label=varnames), size = 5, vjust=1, color=colors[3])
    plot <- plot + geom_segment(data=datapc, aes(x=0, y=0, xend=v1, yend=v2), arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.2,"cm")), alpha=0.75, color=colors[4])
    plot
}
```

Plot as follows:

```
fit <- prcomp(USArrests, scale=T)
PCbiplot(fit, colors=c("black", "black", "red", "yellow"))
```

[image]

If you play around a bit with this function, I am sure you can figure out how to set `xlim` and `ylim` values, etc.

Comment: Thanks, before I got a lot of warnings in the console, but now it's working.
Maybe you could also anwser the added question about colors.

Comment: @Colors - that's what I expected, thanks for the ready-made code
BTW whats with that "copy source code and modify it" in R? I'm not questioning the validity of your anwser, however it's a rather dubious practice from a software engineering standpoint.

Comment: On a final note there I don't expect it's possible to have a rectangular plot with biplot.
Is it the geom_hline and geom_vline calls in your example that I need to change for this?