# Plot partial least squares regression biplot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the `data.frame` below (Source: http://eric.univ-lyon2.fr/~ricco/tanagra/fichiers/en_Tanagra_PLSR_Software_Comparison.pdf)

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
diesel  twodoors    sportsstyle wheelbase   length  width   height  curbweight  enginesize  horsepower  horse_per_weight    conscity    price   symboling
0   1   0   97  172 66  56  2209    109 85  0.0385  8.7 7975    2
0   0   0   100 177 66  54  2337    109 102 0.0436  9.8 13950   2
0   0   0   116 203 72  57  3740    234 155 0.0414  14.7    34184   -1
0   1   1   103 184 68  52  3016    171 161 0.0534  12.4    15998   3
0   0   0   101 177 65  54  2765    164 121 0.0438  11.2    21105   0
0   1   0   90  169 65  52  2756    194 207 0.0751  13.8    34028   3
1   0   0   105 175 66  54  2700    134 72  0.0267  7.6 18344   0
0   0   0   108 187 68  57  3020    120 97  0.0321  12.4    11900   0
0   0   1   94  157 64  51  1967    90  68  0.0346  7.6 6229    1
0   1   0   95  169 64  53  2265    98  112 0.0494  9.0 9298    1
1   0   0   96  166 64  53  2275    110 56  0.0246  6.9 7898    0
0   1   0   100 177 66  53  2507    136 110 0.0439  12.4    15250   2
0   1   1   94  157 64  51  1876    90  68  0.0362  6.4 5572    1
0   0   0   95  170 64  54  2024    97  69  0.0341  7.6 7349    1
0   1   1   95  171 66  52  2823    152 154 0.0546  12.4    16500   1
0   0   0   103 175 65  60  2535    122 88  0.0347  9.8 8921    -1
0   0   0   113 200 70  53  4066    258 176 0.0433  15.7    32250   0
0   0   0   95  165 64  55  1938    97  69  0.0356  7.6 6849    1
1   0   0   97  172 66  56  2319    97  68  0.0293  6.4 9495    2
0   0   0   97  172 66  56  2275    109 85  0.0374  8.7 8495    2"), header = T)
```

and this

**Code**

```
library(plsdepot)
df.plsdepot = plsreg1(df[, 1:11], df[, 14, drop = FALSE], comps = 3)
plot(df.plsdepot, comps = c(1, 2))
```

I got this

**Result**

[image]

The dependent (y) variable here is `symboling`, like price, is function of all other independent variables for the cars (`diesel`, `twodoors`, `sportsstyle`, `wheelbase`, `length`, `width`,   `height`, `curbweight`, `enginesize`,`horsepower`,  `horse_per_weight`)

**Question**

Any help to create the plot above using `ggplot2` but with arrows instead of lines similar to this **[plot](https://www.google.co.nz/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sthda.com%2Fsthda%2FRDoc%2Ffigure%2Ffactor-analysis%2Fprincipal-component-analysis-prcomp-correlation-circle-factoextra-data-mining-1.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sthda.com%2Fenglish%2Fwiki%2Fprincipal-component-analysis-in-r-prcomp-vs-princomp-r-software-and-data-mining&docid=8ZrqNMLitaxt4M&tbnid=ZhgWTXCBUQdQ0M%3A&w=864&h=864&bih=637&biw=1280&ved=0ahUKEwiAzq2q9N7OAhUBq5QKHWKwDJ0QMwglKAkwCQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)** will be highly appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
diesel  twodoors    sportsstyle wheelbase   length  width   height  curbweight  enginesize  horsepower  horse_per_weight    conscity    price   symboling
                          0   1   0   97  172 66  56  2209    109 85  0.0385  8.7 7975    2
                          0   0   0   100 177 66  54  2337    109 102 0.0436  9.8 13950   2
                          0   0   0   116 203 72  57  3740    234 155 0.0414  14.7    34184   -1
                          0   1   1   103 184 68  52  3016    171 161 0.0534  12.4    15998   3
                          0   0   0   101 177 65  54  2765    164 121 0.0438  11.2    21105   0
                          0   1   0   90  169 65  52  2756    194 207 0.0751  13.8    34028   3
                          1   0   0   105 175 66  54  2700    134 72  0.0267  7.6 18344   0
                          0   0   0   108 187 68  57  3020    120 97  0.0321  12.4    11900   0
                          0   0   1   94  157 64  51  1967    90  68  0.0346  7.6 6229    1
                          0   1   0   95  169 64  53  2265    98  112 0.0494  9.0 9298    1
                          1   0   0   96  166 64  53  2275    110 56  0.0246  6.9 7898    0
                          0   1   0   100 177 66  53  2507    136 110 0.0439  12.4    15250   2
                          0   1   1   94  157 64  51  1876    90  68  0.0362  6.4 5572    1
                          0   0   0   95  170 64  54  2024    97  69  0.0341  7.6 7349    1
                          0   1   1   95  171 66  52  2823    152 154 0.0546  12.4    16500   1
                          0   0   0   103 175 65  60  2535    122 88  0.0347  9.8 8921    -1
                          0   0   0   113 200 70  53  4066    258 176 0.0433  15.7    32250   0
                          0   0   0   95  165 64  55  1938    97  69  0.0356  7.6 6849    1
                          1   0   0   97  172 66  56  2319    97  68  0.0293  6.4 9495    2
                          0   0   0   97  172 66  56  2275    109 85  0.0374  8.7 8495    2"), header = T)

library(plsdepot)
library(ggplot2)
df.plsdepot = plsreg1(df[, 1:11], df[, 14, drop = FALSE], comps = 3)
data<-df.plsdepot$cor.xyt
data<-as.data.frame(data)

#Function to draw circle
circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
    r = diameter / 2
    tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
    xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
    yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
    return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}

dat <- circleFun(c(0,0),2,npoints = 100)

ggplot(data=data, aes(t1,t2))+
  ylab("")+xlab("")+ggtitle("Circle of Correlations                                                                     ")+
  theme_bw() +geom_text(aes(label=rownames(data), 
                            colour=ifelse(rownames(data)!='symboling', 'orange','blue')))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("orange","#6baed6"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1))+
  coord_fixed(ylim=c(-1, 1),xlim=c(-1, 1))+xlab("axis 1")+ 
  ylab("axis 2")+ theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="darkgrey"),
                        axis.line.y = element_line(color="darkgrey"))+
  geom_path(data=dat,aes(x,y), colour = "darkgrey")+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "grey"))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(colour = "darkgrey"))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color="darkgrey"))+
  theme(legend.position='none')+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(color="#737373")) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= 0.60, yend= 0.20, color="orange",
           arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.25, yend= -0.35, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= 0.45, yend= 0.75, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= 0.37 , yend=-0.02, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.80, yend= 0.30, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.75, yend= 0.60, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.67, yend= 0.60, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.59, yend= -0.13, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.59, yend= 0.70, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= -0.39, yend= 0.80, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= 0.04, yend= 0.93, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))+
  annotate("segment",x=0, y=0, xend= 0.70, yend= 0.40, color="#6baed6",
           alpha=0.3,arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.3,"cm")))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I got this error `Error in rownames(h) : object 'h' not found`

Comment: i would check your workflow , there is no object h there....you may have mixed it up with the previous question answer

Comment: Thanks. 
In your answer, there is `h` in this line of the code `theme_bw() +geom_text(aes(label=rownames(h),`

Comment: my bad, i changed ``h`` to ``data``!  try it again and let me know if there are any lingering issues!

Comment: There is still `h` in the code above `colour=ifelse(rownames(h)!='symboling', 'orange','blue')))+`
Even after changing both to `data`, I got this error 
`Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: see edits, if there any `` h``  just replace with ``data``

Comment: I have changed any `h` to `data` and I changed `dat` to `data` in `geom_path(data=dat,aes(x,y), colour = "darkgrey")+`. Still, I'm getting this error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found`

Comment: @aelwan Ok i think i fixed it now. I forgot to add the function to draw the circle (and its associated data). Also make sure that the ``geom_path`` data call is set to ``dat`` and not ``data`` -I just cleared my workspace so it should work.

Comment: If I had to use `pls` package instead of the `plsdepot` and I want to get the the correlation between variables and components. You got them through converting `df.plsdepot$cor.xyt` to data.frame. In the `pls` package, I can plot these correlation as follows `library(pls)
Y <- as.matrix(df[,14])
X <- as.matrix(df[,1:11])
df.pls <- mvr(Y ~ X, ncomp = 3, method = "oscorespls", scale = T)
plot(df.pls, "correlation")` but I don't know how to get these values into data.frame. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated?

Comment: @aelwan I would suggest starting a new question post, i'm not sure myself

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188663/correlation-between-variables-and-components-using-pls-package