# Correlation loading plot from PLSR with observations using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, multivariate-testing, pls, biplot

I am investigating the correlation between sensory data and chemical measurements using PLS regression from the `pls` package. Ultimately, I want to display the results in a correlation loading plot as illustrated by the example below. So far I managed to make the plot with X and Y correlation matrices but I haven't figured out a way to project the observations on the plot.

[image: ![correlation plot with observations](https://www.google.no/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjL8buTiZXeAhVDBiwKHSPKDWgQjhx6BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xlstat.com%2Fen%2Fsolutions%2Ffeatures%2Fpartial-least-squares-regression&psig=AOvVaw3NOfDzBjMZFcn-TXm16KaX&ust=1540126569608484)]

As an example, I use the `oliveoil` data set from the `pls` package. I computed the correlation loadings (using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164688/plot-partial-least-squares-regression-biplot-with-ggplot2)) and created a correlation plot using `ggplot2` (This can be done in a simple manner using the `plsdepot` package but I like the versatility of `ggplot`):

```
library(pls)
data("oliveoil")
oil <- plsr(sensory ~ chemical, scale = TRUE, data = oliveoil)

scores <- oil$scores
sc1 <- scores[,1]
sc2 <- scores[,2]
scores <- as.data.frame(cbind(sc1, sc2))
cl_plsr <- cor(model.matrix(oil), scores)
df_cor <- as.data.frame(cl_plsr)
df_depend_cor <- as.data.frame(cor(oliveoil$sensory, scores))
plot_loading_correlation  <-  rbind(df_cor, df_depend_cor)
plot_loading_correlation1 <- setNames(plot_loading_correlation, c("comp1", "comp2"))

#Function to draw circle
circleFun <- function(center = c(0,0),diameter = 1, npoints = 100){
  r = diameter / 2
  tt <- seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx <- center[1] + r * cos(tt)
  yy <- center[2] + r * sin(tt)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}

dat_plsr <- circleFun(c(0,0),2,npoints = 100)

library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

p <- ggplot(data=plot_loading_correlation1, aes(comp1, comp2))+
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), size=.2, linetype = 3)+ 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 0), size=.2, linetype = 3)+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(plot_loading_correlation1), 
              colour = c("black","black","black","black","black", 
                         "red","red","red","red","red","red")))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-1,2.5, by=0.5))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(-1.5,2.5, by=0.5))+
  coord_fixed(ylim=c(-1, 1), xlim=c(-1, 1)) + xlab("PC 1") + ylab("PC 2")+ 
  geom_path(data=dat_plsr ,
        aes(x,y), colour = "darkgrey")+
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(colour = "black"))+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color="black"))+
  theme(legend.position='none')+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  geom_point(data = plot_loading_correlation1,
         aes(x=comp1, y=comp2), 
         colour = c("blue","blue","blue","blue","blue",
                    "red","red","red","red","red","red"), 
         shape = c(21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,22),          
         fill = c("blue","blue","blue","blue","blue",
                  "red","red","red","red","red","red"),
         size = 2.2)
p
```

[image: Correlation loading plot from ggplot2 without the observations]

How can I project individual observations to that plot as illustrated in the example above? Should the scores be scaled so that they fit on the correlation loadings scale (from -1 to 1)? And is that acceptable scientifically?

Comment: I think you can always normalize the scores without loosing its variation. The plot is used more for grouping and exploration rather than actual measurement of scores, it should be acceptable.

Comment: Thanks @TheRimalaya. I think adding the observations adds a useful layer of information to the plot especially if you want to relate individual samples to their levels of measured chemical or perceived sensory characteristics. I am quite new to PLSR and the example illustrated above was generated by another program than R so I don't know the standard method to fit the observations to the correlation plot but I have seen several examples like this one in research papers. I have tried normalizing the scores using `scale(scores)` but the results still fall outside of the range -1, 1.