# A self-written code for biplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, pca

I would like to have my own script that plots loadings and scores of PCA. 
The main problem is that loadings and scores are not of the same unit measurements (in my data). I assume I would need to scale loadings somehow in my code.
Here I tried to have an example of biplot of PCA on iris data, but this code gives an error:

> Error: Don't know how to add o to a plot

```
# mybiplot
# load data in
data <- (iris)
iris <- data[,1:4]
species <- data[,5]

# apply pca
pca <- prcomp(iris, center = TRUE,scale. = TRUE)

# extract scores and loadings
scores <- as.data.frame(pca$x)
loadings <- as.data.frame(pca$rotation) 
label <- species

# make biplot
p = ggplot()+
    geom_point(data = scores, aes(x=PC1, y=PC2, colour = factor(label)))+
    geom_segment(data = loadings, aes(x=0,y=0,xend=PC1,yend=PC2),
    arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.1,"cm")), color = "#DCDCDC")+
    geom_text(data = loadings, aes(x=PC2, y=PC3, label=label),color="#006400")
p
```

I would like to get rid of this error (and understand why it have happened and what is wrong with the code), and also how can I get scores and loadings in one biplot. 
biplot(PCA) obviously works, but I need to have a self-written code that is more flexible. ggbiplot() and autoplot() did not work at all.

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578355/plotting-pca-biplot-with-ggplot2

Comment: @DMR  I do not think this is a duplicate of the question that you cite.  Yes,  they are both about biplots, but this question is not how do you write a plot from scratch but rather what is wrong with this code.

Comment: The most voted answer from this post actually does not work. It is from 2011.
Error: geom_hline requires the following missing aesthetics: yintercept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `geom_text` layer

```
geom_text(data = loadings, aes(x=PC2, y=PC3, label=label),color="#006400")
```

Both `loadings$PC2` and `loadings$PC3` have length 4, but `label` has length 150. These do not go together.

Comment: right! probably need to use as.factor() function to extract four factors from the table, instead of having all the table. Thanks!